# Debug Error Code 10 in Windows 10 for NFC device

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, nfc

I have two Windows 10 (1803) tablet pcs equipped with a PCI-Express NFC reader. In the first one, NFC works like a charm, the second sadly doesn't.

In the second device, when I open the Device manager there's not a single "Proximity Device" in the list. The funny thing is that when i bring any nfc tag close to the reader, it makes a sound, confirming that the hardware reader is alive.

When I try to install its drivers (recommended by the tablet's vendor) the installer crashes with a "No such device" Error.

Adding a legacy device from the device manager seems to have no effect either, since it will just create a dummy proximity device that cannot start (Error code 10). To get to this last state, I tried **many** different drivers available online.

As a desperate act, i copied every nxp* driver from the other identical tablet. It won't work either.

How can I actually debug this error? If it is a hardware related issue I have to prove it

Comment: If you exchange the two cards between the devices does the tablet with the non-working card start to function as expected?

Comment: Sadly I can't try since it would invalidate warranty

Comment: Go through the warranty claim process in that case.  Without the ability to confirm if this is a hardware or software configuration problem, or provide us the required information to make that determination, this answer is next to impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I thought Windows gave me a way of checking if some component was actually plugged in or something like that but seems like it's not the case. I'll answer my question once i manage to solve the issue